# Python doesn't recognize new member of a class

Tags: python, numpy

I am adding new members to the constructor of an existing class: `Account`. What I am trying to add to `Account` class is a 2D `numpy` array which is defined as:

```
self._path_payment = np.zeros((4, self._parent._simulation_number))
```

where `self._parent` is a `Portfolio` class which contains `simulation_number`. Also I defined a get function for it:

```
    def get_path_payment(self):
        return self._path_payment
```

And later on, I tried to get access to this piece of information from `Portfolio` class by:

```
path_payment = account.get_path_payment()
```

where `account` is an object of `Account` class.

However, I got following error:

> AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'get_path_payment'

It works well before I added `_path_payment` into `Account` class, so I guess Python doesn't recognize the new member?

May I know how to work around this?  Thanks a lot.

**EDIT1:**

The Account class is like:

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self, ....):
        ......
        self._path_payment = np.zeros((4, self._parent.get_horizon()))
        ......

    def get_path_payment(self):
        return self._path_payment
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is an example which is related to the question, it is with in `Portfolio` class:

```
path_payment = account.get_path_payment()
path1_number += path_payment[0, simu]
path2_number += path_payment[1, simu]
path3_number += path_payment[2, simu]
path4_number += path_payment[3, simu]
```

Comment: Could you show more of the `Account` class? Where is `get_path_payment` defined?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just edit the post, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any reason why you would get that error. Are you sure the indentation is correct? Can you access `account._path_payment` directly? Is there another definition of `Account` somewhere?

Comment: Please post an actual example that reproduces the problem. I ran [this simplified](http://ideone.com/K3pQrT) version and it works.

Comment: @ChangeMyName how are you instantiating `account`? Are you doing `account = Account()`?

Comment: @SaulloCastro There is a parameter list such as `para1`, 'para2', .... I instantiate `account` as `account = Account(para1, para2, ....)`

Comment: @luk32 I wonder it would work in the same way. Could it be some internal linkage failure?

Comment: You are not showing actual code, nor providing an example that reproduces the problem. That is pretty much a question that cannot be helped.

Comment: @luk32 just updated it. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @ChangeMyName That doesn't really help much. Create a complete example. Where you define that class, create a instance of that class and get the reported error. We should be able to copy\paste and run the code.

Comment: please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces your problem... You may even find what your error is while writing your SSCCE..

Answer (score 0):

the code you're pasting should definitely work fine...

though, are there other method from `account` working as expected?
can you write a `print(type(account))` just before the failing line?

Your error is pretty typical of a shadowing error. You think you're using an account error, whereas you're actually dealing with another instance object, whether it is another variable having the same name coming from a greedy import or a function parameter.

But that's a wild and blind guess ;-)

Comment: I am not sure if this should be an answer... The problem cannot be reproduced, and presented codes do not show anything.

Comment: even though it's a guess, that's definitely a possible issue that could help the OP solve his problem. I totally may be wrong, but for future reference it's definitely a common enough error for future readers to check that first thing... Until the post gets closed if it gets closed.

Comment: Maybe, I just got a feeling that this should be a comment. Maybe I'm wrong. Posting wild guesses as answers is a very grey area to me. Now this does not solve a problem, but should help people to debug better, I won't judge if it's fine or not. IMO it's debatable.

Comment: welcome to the grey area between comments and answers ;-) I begun writing this as a comment, then it would have been too long and hard to read, and by weeding out possibilities, it looks to me very probable that's the problem the OP is facing. But the OP not answering, and the question about to be put on hold... We may never know ;-)